# What is the state of particle at time $t$ if at $t=0$ it is in an eigenstate of $\hat{A}$, and $\hat{A}$ commutes with $\hat{H}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, commutator, time-evolution

**EDIT**: added (assuming $\lambda$ to be non-degenerate). Based on the specifics of the question, we don't in fact know whether this is the case, so it may be that $\left|\lambda\right>$ is not an energy eigenstate...

Consider a particle which at time $t=0$ is in a state $\left|\Psi,t=0\right> =\left|\lambda\right>$, which is an eigenstate of the operator $\hat{A}$, such that $\hat{A}\left|\lambda\right>=\lambda\left|\lambda\right>$, where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $\left|\lambda\right>$. Further, suppose that $[\hat{H},\hat{A}]=0$, and that $\hat{H}$ is dependent on time.

How can it be shown that for all $t$ the particle exists in state $\left|\lambda\right>$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$?

What follows is the approach I've taken so far.

$$
[\hat{H},\hat{A}]=\hat{H}\hat{A}-\hat{A}\hat{H}=0.
$$
This obviously means that:
$$
\hat{H}\hat{A}\left|\lambda\right>=\hat{A}\hat{H}\left|\lambda\right>=\lambda\hat{H}\left|\lambda\right>,
$$
which implies that $\left|\lambda\right>$ is an eigenstate of $\hat{H}$ at $t=0$ (assuming $\lambda$ to be non-degenerate).

It is after this point that I don't know how to proceed. What I think I have to show next is that the more general state when $t>0$, $\left|\Psi,t\right>$, is always an eigenstate of $\hat{H}$, but with the general form of $\left|\Psi,t\right>$being such that:
$$
\left|\Psi,t\right>=\sum_{n}C_n(t)\left|n\right>,
$$
I am not sure how to go about doing this. I am thinking that I have to solve the general Schrodinger equation:
$$
i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left|\Psi,t\right>=\hat{H}\left|\Psi,t\right>,
$$
where:
$$
\hat{H}=\hat{H_0}+\hat{V}(t),
$$
with $\hat{H_0}$ being independent of time. Is this correct? And, if so, how can I show that all $C_n(t)=0$ except for the one in corresponding to the initial state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of the question is that $\hat H = \hat H(t)$ is time-dependent, but $[\hat H(t), \hat A] = 0$ at all times.
Then your argumentation shows that $|\lambda\rangle$ is actually an eigenstate of $\hat H(t)$ at all times $t$, only the respective eigenvalue can change:
$$ \hat H(t) |\lambda\rangle = E_\lambda(t) |\lambda\rangle . $$

---

To find the solution $|\psi(t)\rangle$ of the Schrödinger equation (so that $|\psi(0)\rangle = |\lambda\rangle$), we can simply make the *ansatz* that
$$ |\psi(t)\rangle = C(t) |\lambda\rangle . \tag{1} $$
Plugging that in yields $\mathrm i\hbar\, \dot C(t) = E_\lambda(t) C(t)$ which is an ordinary differential equation that can be easily solved.
This shows that our ansatz was correct and (1) indeed solves the Schrödinger equation.

---

Another way of seeing this is that the solution of the Schrödinger equation can be generally written as
$$ |\psi(t)\rangle = \mathcal T\! \mathrm e^{-\mathrm i/\hbar\, \int_0^t \hat H(\tau) \mathrm d\tau} |\psi(0)\rangle , $$
where $\mathcal T\! \mathrm e$ is the time-ordered exponential.
The time-ordered exponential can be defined in the following way:
$$ |\psi(t)\rangle = \lim_{N \to \infty} \mathrm e^{-\mathrm i \hat H(t_N) \Delta t / \hbar} \cdots \mathrm e^{-\mathrm i \hat H(t_0) \Delta t / \hbar} |\lambda\rangle , $$
where $\Delta t = t / N$ and $t_k = (k/N) \Delta t$.
Now note that $|\lambda\rangle$ is an eigenstate of every "slice" $\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i \hat H(t_k) \Delta t / \hbar}$, and therefore an eigenstate of the whole time-evolution operator.